# Sensitive movie scrubbing with AVPlayer

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, avfoundation, avplayer

I'm building a movie player which requires a highly sensitive scrubbing feature. My aim is to allow the user to scrub frame by frame if he selects the highest sensitivity.

Currently I'm using the method:

`[player seekToTime:CMTimeMakeWithSeconds(duration*(Float64) slider.value, 600)];`

but I'm far from the sensitivity I wish to achieve. Can someone advice or point out better method or even frameworks to get this feature done.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Solve this problem. Somehow it slipped from my eyes but there is a method that does exactly that:

```
[player seekToTime:CMTimeMakeWithSeconds(duration*(Float64)value  , 600) 
      toleranceBefore:kCMTimeZero 
       toleranceAfter:kCMTimeZero];
```

The `toleranceBefore` and the `toleranceAfter` are set to zero which means it will get exactly to the point you are searching but it will take more time to decode the frame.

Comment: are you satisfied with the decoding time? I am looking for exactly the same functionality.

Answer (score 0):

Just want to mention a limitation of HLS here. Even though you specify the tolerance 0, it is not possible to seek in the middle of any ts segment. Once you lift your finger from scrubber to seek a position, the player will start playing the video from the nearest TS segment.